# Services stops when i close the activity

Tags: android, service

My project one service and one activity
in my activity i am having 2 spinners and 1 button

i am starting the service from my activity.
in the service it checks the onItemSelected on both dropdown list and run the code.

it works fine till is activity is active. if it is killed the service stops.

service is checking again n again from dropdownlist which is not accessible after i kill activity.

how can save the selected item in services and use it .

in mainactivity

```
    dropdown = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.spinner1);
    dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
    dropdown2 = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.Spinner01);
    dropdown2.setOnItemSelectedListener(new CustomOnItemSelectedListener());
```

i have used below code in services..

```
    public void onStart(Intent intent, int startId) {

     String m1 = (String) MainActivity.dropdown.getSelectedItem();
      String m1 = (String) MainActivity.dropdown2.getSelectedItem();

    if (m1 = "xyz") 
    {
   switch m2:           
        //code
    }
    else {
        switch m2:
          //code
         }
```

Comment: LOL Your topic is funny :-) Service isn't what it is

Comment: And yes if you force close your app, then service will get close as well i.e. from Application manager

Comment: kill the activity in the sense removing from recent apps

Comment: how do you know the service has stopped?

Comment: we can check running services in emulator

Answer (score 1):

you can save your value in SharedPrefs

```
PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).edit().putString("value","myvalue").apply();
```

and get it next time this way

```
String v = PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(this).getString("value","");
```